# django- how to serve an image in all templates of django app?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to show user's avatar in all pages of my django project.
I use an `<img>` tag in base.html and in the href I write: `{{ request.user.profile.get_avatar }}`.
but it does not work properly.
in the first page of project it works but in another pages does not work.

The problem is for addresses.
for example in index page with url www.mysite.com/index the image shows. but in www.mysite.com/v1/v2/v3  image does not show.

This is the get_avatar method of profile class:

```
def get_avatar(self):
    if self.avatar:
        return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL + str(self.avatar))
    else:
        return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL + str('avatars/student.jpg'))
```

[view of not working picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0L51.png)

```
def profile_me(request):
    the_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    klasses = KlassStudents.objects.filter(student=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'ejazeostad/profile/profile.html', {'profile': the_profile, 'klasses': klasses})
```

Comment: Please show a view that does not work.

Comment: Did you add `'django.core.context_processors.request',` to your `TEMPLATES = []` variable in settings.py?

Comment: @Hybrid this "django.template.context_processors.request" is in the TEMPLATES variable... Now i add 'django.core.context_processors.request' to TEMPLATES variable and this error generated: No module named 'django.core.context_processors'

Comment: That makes sense, it is the newer version of the requests context processor...as @Alasdair said, can you provide a view that doesn't work?

Comment: @Hybrid https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0L51.png

Comment: i add it to question body

Comment: What is `settings.MEDIA_URL`?

Comment: Did you try `{{ the_profile.get_avatar }}` ?

Comment: @Alasdair media_url and media_root: 
MEDIA_URL = 'files/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "uploaded_files")

Comment: @jpic no. this is in the base.html , the_profile will not send to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MEDIA_URL` setting should be an absolute URL, e.g.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/files/'
```

At the moment, you have a relative URL `'files/'`. That means that the URL changes depending on which page you are on. When you visit `www.mysite.com/index`, the relative URL expands to `www.mysite.com/files/avatars/avatar.jpg` which works, but when you visit `www.mysite.com/v1/v2/v3`, the relative URL is expanded to `www.mysite.com/v1/v2/files/avatars/avatar.jpg` which is incorrect.

Comment: exactly! because of not using / in the beginning of MEDIA_URL, in every page, picture's address (url) was changing.